# Checking if there is not record with that id

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I've just started to learn about laravel and I want to use this framework with It's advantages. I'm asking this question to learn the right way to this with laravel.

It is printing the post from posts table which has the same id with $id.

```
<?php
    class PostsController extends BaseController{

        public function singlePost($id)
        {
            $thePost = Posts::find($id);
            return View::make('singlePost')->with('thePost', $thePost);
        }

    }
```

Normally I do check if there is a post that's id equal to $id and if that is, return view so forth. Isn't there better way to do this with laravel like you can do with route filters.

Shortly,

- How to know if there is post with that id?
- How to throw exception if there is not?
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route Model Binding might be an option however a more universal solution is `findOrFail`
`findOrFail` will either return the model or throw a `ModelNotFoundException` which will display as a 404 page.

```
$thePost = Posts::findOrFail($id);
return View::make('singlePost')->with('thePost', $thePost);
```

To just check for existence you can use `find` and then compare with `null`:

```
$thePost = Posts::find($id);
if($thePost != null){
    // post exists
}
```

Or simpler, just a *truthy* value:

```
$thePost = Posts::find($id);
if($thePost){
    // post exists
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know this is the way but the thing I wonder is if there is another way to this with laravel :)

Comment: Why do you need another way? In other words what do you don't like about this one?

Answer (score 0):

See ["Route Model Binding"](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-model-binding) in the documentation.

```
Route::model('post', 'Post', function() {
    // do something if Post is not found
    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
});

Route::get('post/{post}', function(Post $post) {
    return View::make('singlePost')->with('thePost', $post);
});
```

You could also just replace `find()` with `findOrFail()` in your code, which would throw an exception of a post wasn't found with that ID.

Comment: Thanks man! How can i change the fail exception when i use findOrFail?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "change" it, but you can respond to it any way you like with a standard PHP `try`/`catch` block.